# Generate Excel file using XML and XSL in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel

How to generate Excel file using an XML and XSL file in C#/VB.NET? 
I have the required XML and XSL file. BUT I dont know how to generate an Excel file from out of these. 
Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_that_supports_Office_Open_XML#Programmatic_support_2

Comment: Thanks @amald, Does OOXML support older versions of Microsoft office? like MS Office 2003, XP, 2000, etc?

Comment: Also, does it allow to password protect the Excel sheet?

Comment: Google for that. OpenXML data are freely available in net.

Comment: I could find, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168011/excel-file-password-protection-with-open-xml-sdk) to protect OpenXML generated excel file but I want the ability that the user can selectively set protection such as the ability to allow certain settings as shown in the image ( ![Valid XHTML](http://oi39.tinypic.com/14nd7wj.jpg) ).