# How to enable read only permision to some specified cells and sheets in excel using openxml in c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am reading XML data then I pasted to data-set and the I created spreadsheet and copied the data to to sheets in spreadsheet.So now I want to only allow some sheets and cells to read-only. To prevent to no changes to headers and data in some sheets, So I am posting code used to convert the XML to excel using open XML. So I need to prevent write for some sheets and also cells some sheets.

```
public void ExportDSToExcel(DataSet ds, string dest)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(dest, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        uint sheetId = 1;

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);                

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
            string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId =
                    sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtname.Text != null)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
            {
        string myXMLfile = "/uploads/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(myXMLfile));
        string dest = "D:/uploads/" + txtname.Text+".xlsx";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {

            ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblstatus.Text=(ex.ToString());
        }
            ExportDSToExcel(ds, dest);

    }
            else
            {
               lblstatus.Text = "Please Upload the file ";
            }
        }
        else {

            lblstatus.Text = "Please enter the name ";
        }

    }
}
```

thanks in advance so please help me to find solution in this code.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? I don't see anything in the way of trying to make cells readonly in your code?

Comment: Searching for "lock cells using OpenXML" yielded some good looking answers, including one from our very own StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257842/read-only-or-lock-the-particular-cells-or-rows-using-open-xml-sdk

Comment: sry sir  i dint tried to make read only .because i dint know how to take sheet-wise or headerwise

Answer (score 0):

We can customise protection by password in different means.For making excel sheet specified area or column or row as read only or a full sheet into read only by giving protection to sheet by password.If we want to protect whole sheet use this code

```
 PageMargins pageM = sheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<PageMargins>();
                   SheetProtection sheetProtection = new SheetProtection();
                   sheetProtection.Password = "admin";
                   sheetProtection.Sheet = true;
                   sheetProtection.Objects = true;
                   sheetProtection.Scenarios = true;
                   ProtectedRanges pRanges = new ProtectedRanges();
                   ProtectedRange pRange = new ProtectedRange();
                   ListValue<StringValue> lValue = new ListValue<StringValue>();
                   lValue.InnerText = ""; //set cell which you want to make it editable
                   pRange.SequenceOfReferences = lValue;
                   pRange.Name = "not allow editing";
                   pRanges.Append(pRange);
                   sheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(sheetProtection, pageM);
                   sheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(pRanges, pageM);
```

If we want specified page as read only then first give a condition filter by name then give this code .In this code  lValue.InnerText = ""; is null so we are not mention cells have permission to overcome this protection. If we mention the cells we can edit up to that limit.