# How to make a particular sheet 'Read Only' using OpenXml?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have filled the excel sheet with data. And before allowing the user to download it, I  have to make one of the sheet  'Read Only'. I tried to use 'SheetProtection' but that makes me lose all the data of that sheet.

Comment: i think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168011/excel-file-password-protection-with-open-xml-sdk) will help you

Comment: Keep in mind you can't prevent a determined user from bypassing these "security" measures. The protections available in Excel are not meant to be true security.

Comment: Yeah. There is no way I can make it 'Read Only'. At max, Password Protection is possible. That will suffice as of now. Thanks.